# How can JavaFX app get the list of files dropped onto a dock icon of non-running app?

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I need my JavaFX application to be notified when the user drops files onto the dock icon. This works fine, via Apple Java extensions (OpenFilesEvent), if the application has already been started before the drop happens.

However, if the application is not yet running, it just starts up clean - no command line args, no Apple specific events.

How can the application find out what those files were?